# How come my tree child node id is not what I set in ExtJS?

Tags: extjs

I dynamically append a child to a tree node. I expect the child node has id, record.id. But I get the generated id from ExtJS.
    parent.appendChild({
    id : record.id,
    text : record.value
    });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because your are confusing two different concepts. Every tree node has a visual representation and a model behind then, there are two ids: the visual element id and the model id.

You are setting the model id and not the visual element id. Please, take a look at this code:

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
    root: {
        expanded: true,
        children: []
    }
});

var tree = Ext.create('Ext.tree.Panel', {
    title: 'Simple Tree',
    width: 200,
    height: 150,
    store: store,
    rootVisible: false,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});

var root = tree.getRootNode();
var appendedRecord = root.appendChild({id: 1, text: 'juan'});
alert('component id: ' + appendedRecord.id + '    model id: ' + appendedRecord.get('id'));​
```

Better, take a look at the same code in jsfiddle here and don´t forget press Run

http://jsfiddle.net/HReqT/

**Update:**

Extjs is who assign the visual element ids, you cannot do it (or at least you shouldn´t do that)